# User profiles management in QGIS

Tags: qgis, user-interface

1. Is there a default solution for choosing certain profile before GUI of QGIS app will load ? I want to be able to choose one profile from set of profiles always before GUI loads.
2. Is there a way to disable GUI in QGIS app before receiving master password for certain profile ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I' ve made an external application to serve my purposes.

As far as i know the answers are:
1. No there is no such default option.
2. Yes it is possible but after modification of many dependencies and files.

Answer (score 0):

"Settings | Options | User Profiles | Choose profile at start up" works fine for me.